# Cut Hue Light Strip and connect pieces in parallel

Tags: lighting, home-automation

is it possible to separate a hue light strip using heat like shown [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cutting-and-Reconnecting-Hue-Light-Strip-Plus-Segm/) and connect the pieces using Y-connectors in parallel?

I want to split a Light Strip and use just one piece per stair in my stairway, connecting them to a single bus. They should all be connected to the same controller to allow a smooth light scene. Obviously using one controller per stair is not optimal :)

Thanks for your ideas!

**Update**

The setup should look like this:

```
[CTRL]
  |
  |---[PIECE OF STRIP]
  |
  |---[PIECE OF STRIP]
  |
  |---[PIECE OF STRIP]
  |
  |---[PIECE OF STRIP]
  |
```

Will the controller be able to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.   In fact it's a good idea to parallel if you have more than about 10 feet of strips - those internal pathways on the strips will cause a lot of voltage drop if they're too long.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my update. So you think this will be fine? I'm concernced as the controller does in fact communicate using a clock and data.

Comment: Except that a parallel circuit compounds current flow, and the controller may fry.

Comment: The length of the overall strip resp. the number of lights won't change. I need only one strip. Aren't the pieces kind of parallel internally, too? Like with a christmas lightning, where pieces may fail.

Comment: @DominikP "kind of parallel internally" is exactly how I'd describe it.   Look at the "cut here" lines. If you consider everything *between* cut lines to be the smallest divisible unit (which it is), then all "units" are indeed in parallel.  Cutting them and wiring them in parallel changes nothing electrically, they were in parallel before.